# how can I access all values in TreeStore

Tags: c#, gtk

I have a `TreeStore` and I want to walk through its values in a loop and compare some values with something.

How can I do that?

I tried a simple loop like

```
TreeIter iter = new TreeIter();

if (Values.GetIterFirst(out iter))
{
    while (Values.IterNext(ref iter))
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

but that doesn't work

Comment: Unless all the items are children of the root, you'll need to check to see which nodes have children and then do a first/next loop on those as well.

Comment: not really, per my answer

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that `Foreach` function can do this:

```
    private bool feIter(TreeModel model, TreePath path, TreeIter iter)
    {
        if (Values.GetValue(iter, 1) == ObjectStore)
        {
            return true; // exit loop
        }
        return false; // continue in loop
    }

    public void Blah()
    {
        Values.Foreach(feIter);
    }
```